# Infinite recursion when running DART unit test

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I have a simple example of DART unit test when testing is done in the asynchronously started methods. I observe all the tests, starting from the very first one, being repeated over and over with the last test being repeated one time more in every loop. Here is the code:

```dart
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'dart:html';
    import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';
    import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
    import 'package:utf/utf.dart';
    var repositoryURL = r"http://usryeddrint451v.asg.com:8080/ddrint/ServiceDirect/getRepositories";

    void main() {
        test('Test 1',(){
         var a=10;
         expect(a, equals(10));
        });
        serverTrip();
        test('Test 4',(){
         var b=10;
         expect(b, equals(10));
        });
    }

    void serverTrip(){
      test('Server trip test', () {
      var repositoryURL = r"http://usryeddrint451v.asg.com:8080/ddrint/ServiceDirect/getRepositories";  
      var bytes = encodeUtf8("demouser:luminist");
           var base64 = CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64(bytes);
           var auth = "Basic " + base64;
           var httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
           httpRequest.withCredentials = true;
           httpRequest.open('POST', repositoryURL);
           httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
           httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Authoriz

ation", auth);
       httpRequest.onLoadEnd.listen((ee) =>checkProgress());     
       httpRequest.onError.listen((ee) => handleError());
       print('Sending request');
       httpRequest.send('');
  });
}

void checkProgress(){
  print("Print -- Called checkProgress");

  var bytes = encodeUtf8("demouser:luminist");
       var base64 = CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64(bytes);
       var auth = "Basic " + base64;
       var httpRequest = new HttpRequest();

       httpRequest.withCredentials = true;

       httpRequest.open('POST', repositoryURL);
       httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);

       httpRequest.onLoadEnd.listen((ee) => checkProgress1());     
       httpRequest.onError.listen((ee) => handleError());
       httpRequest.send('');
}

void checkProgress1(){
  test('Check progress1 test',(){
    var a=10;
    expect(a, equals(10));
  });
}


void handleError(){
  print("Error");
}
```

Here is the output:

```
unittest-suite-wait-for-done
Sending request
PASS: Test 1
PASS: Server trip test
PASS: Test 4

All 3 tests passed.
unittest-suite-success
Print -- Called checkProgress
unittest-suite-wait-for-done
Sending request
PASS: Test 1
PASS: Server trip test
PASS: Test 4
PASS: Check progress1 test

All 4 tests passed.
unittest-suite-success
Print -- Called checkProgress
unittest-suite-wait-for-done
Sending request
PASS: Test 1
PASS: Server trip test
PASS: Test 4
PASS: Check progress1 test
PASS: Check progress1 test

All 5 tests passed.
unittest-suite-success
Print -- Called checkProgress
unittest-suite-wait-for-done
Sending request
PASS: Test 1
PASS: Server trip test
PASS: Test 4
PASS: Check progress1 test
PASS: Check progress1 test
PASS: Check progress1 test

All 6 tests passed.
unittest-suite-success
Print -- Called checkProgress
unittest-suite-wait-for-done
Sending request
PASS: Test 1
PASS: Server trip test
PASS: Test 4
PASS: Check progress1 test
PASS: Check progress1 test
PASS: Check progress1 test
PASS: Check progress1 test

All 7 tests passed.
unittest-suite-success
Print -- Called checkProgress
unittest-suite-wait-for-done
Sending request
PASS: Test 1
PASS: Server trip test
PASS: Test 4
PASS: Check progress1 test
PASS: Check progress1 test
PASS: Check progress1 test
PASS: Check progress1 test
PASS: Check progress1 test
```

Why asynchronous methods repeat the whole test suite?

Edit:

I tried to replace the main method with:

```
void main() {
    test('Test 1',(){
     var a=10;
     expect(a, equals(10));
    });
    test('Server trip test', (){
        serverTrip();
    });
    test('Test 4',(){
     var b=10;
     expect(b, equals(10));
    });
}
```

and to remote the test from the serverTrip body.

This seemd to guarantee calling serverTrip when it was expected.

The output was like this:

```
unittest-suite-wait-for-done
Test 1
Server trip
Sending request
Test 4
PASS: Test 1
PASS: Server trip
PASS: Test 4

All 3 tests passed.
unittest-suite-success
Print -- Called checkProgress
unittest-suite-wait-for-done
Test 1
Server trip
Sending request
Test 4
PASS: Test 1
PASS: Server trip
PASS: Test 4
PASS: Check progress1 test

All 4 tests passed.
unittest-suite-success
Print -- Called checkProgress
unittest-suite-wait-for-done
Test 1
Server trip
Sending request
Test 4
PASS: Test 1
PASS: Server trip
PASS: Test 4
PASS: Check progress1 test
PASS: Check progress1 test

All 5 tests passed.
....
```

and ad infinitum

Comment: You are aware that `serverTrip();` is executed before both tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are aware that `serverTrip();` is executed before both tests?

Why do you do this

void serverTrip(){
      test('Server trip test', () {

in the main of your test you should only have test methods

```dart
void main(args) {

  // some initializtation (unittest, ...) may go here

  setUp(() {});
  tearDown(() {});
  test('xxx1', () { testcode});
  test('xxx2', () { testcode});
  // or
  group('g1' () {
    setUp(() {});
    tearDown(() {});
    test('xxx1', () { testcode});
    test('xxx2', () { testcode});
 });

  group('g2' () {
    setUp(() {});
    tearDown(() {});
    test('xxx3', () { testcode});
    test('xxx4', () { testcode});
 });
}
```

I'll take a look what could cause the recursion and update my answer

changing it to this fixes the recursion

```dart
void main() {
  test('Test 1', () {
    var a = 10;
    expect(a, equals(10));
  });

  test('Server trip test', () {
    serverTrip();
  });
  //serverTrip();
  test('Test 4', () {
    var b = 10;
    expect(b, equals(10));
  });

  test('checkProgress1', () {
    checkProgress1();
  });
}

void serverTrip() {
  //test('Server trip test', () {
  var repositoryURL =
      r"http://usryeddrint451v.asg.com:8080/ddrint/ServiceDirect/getRepositories";
  var bytes = encodeUtf8("demouser:luminist");
  var base64 = CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64(bytes);
  var auth = "Basic " + base64;
  var httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
  httpRequest.withCredentials = true;
  httpRequest.open('GET', repositoryURL);
  httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
  httpRequest.onLoadEnd.listen((ee) => checkProgress());
  httpRequest.onError.listen((ee) => handleError());
  print('Sending request');
  httpRequest.send('');
  // });
}

void checkProgress1() {
  var a = 10;
  expect(a, equals(10));
}
```

**EDIT**

add some guards to make async tests work

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:utf/utf.dart';
var repositoryURL =
    r"'http://127.0.0.1:3030/playground/test/interacting_test_s/index.html'";

void main() {
  test('Test 1', () {
    var a = 10;
    expect(a, equals(10));
  });

  test('Server trip test', () {

    // create a callback, the unittest framework expects this callback to be called once
    var callback = expectAsync((){}); 
    serverTrip(callback);
  });
  //serverTrip();
  test('Test 4', () {
    var b = 10;
    expect(b, equals(10));
  });

  test('checkProgress1', () {
    // create a callback, the unittest framework expects this callback to be called once
    var callback = expectAsync((){});
    checkProgress1(callback);
  });
}

void serverTrip(callback) {
  //test('Server trip test', () {
  var repositoryURL =
      r"http://usryeddrint451v.asg.com:8080/ddrint/ServiceDirect/getRepositories";
  var bytes = encodeUtf8("demouser:luminist");
  var base64 = CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64(bytes);
  var auth = "Basic " + base64;
  var httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
  //    httpRequest.withCredentials = true;
  httpRequest.open('GET', repositoryURL);
  //    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
  //        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  //    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
  httpRequest.onLoadEnd.listen((ee) => checkProgress(callback));
  httpRequest.onError.listen((ee) => handleError());
  print('Sending request');
  httpRequest.send('');
  // });
}

void checkProgress(callback) {
  print("Print -- Called checkProgress");

  var bytes = encodeUtf8("demouser:luminist");
  var base64 = CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64(bytes);
  var auth = "Basic " + base64;
  var httpRequest = new HttpRequest();

  //httpRequest.withCredentials = true;

  httpRequest.open('GET', repositoryURL);
  //  httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
  //      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  //  httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);

  httpRequest.onLoadEnd.listen((ee) => checkProgress1(callback));
  httpRequest.onError.listen((ee) => handleError());
  httpRequest.send('');
}

void checkProgress1(callback) {
  var a = 10;
  expect(a, equals(10));

  // the callback is passed as parameter, it could also be a top level variable
  // but this way it is dangerous that the tests interfere with each other
  // the second test might get executed while the first waits for a response to
  // the HttpRequest it made
  callback();
}


void handleError() {
  print("Error");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So, you, basically, removed the test from asynchronous call to checkProgress1 and replaced it with the synchronous call in the main. I guess it is not advisable to run tests in the asynchronously called methods, correct?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What I did is that all `test` are called directly from `main` and that the test code is executed from within a test. I don't know what you mean by `not advisable to run tests in the asynchronously called methods`. As stated, tests are all registered using `test` in `main` to be executed by the unit test framework. You can of course run async code in your unit tests but it may need some guards to ensure all tests are finished before the unit test framework quits (for example `var callback = expectAsync(...);`)

Comment: HttpRequest is async and may need such a guard, I didn't check if the test work properly. The unit test framework will report all tests successfully before any HttpRequest was event sent. But that is another story. You can't solve this with an approach you took in your question.

Comment: I extended my answer. I added a copy of your tests where such guards are added. I have commented out some code just to make the tests work in my environment.